# Bootstrap Calendar - connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I use this https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar calendar for my app and I get this error

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in .../events.json.php on line 9
```

Could you please take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong:

```
$db    = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$sql   = sprintf('SELECT * FROM table_events');

$out = array();
foreach($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    $out[] = array(
        'id' => $row->id,
        'title' => $row->name,
        'url' => $row->url,
        'start' => strtotime($row->datetime) . '000',
        'end' => strtotime($row->datetime_end) .'000'
    );
}

echo json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'result' => $out));
exit;
```

Basically, I don't get back any result in my calendar.

Thanks.

Comment: I  completed my answer, try it

Answer (score 3):

it's because `$db->query($sql)` doesn't return an object, you write `$row->id`, but it's must be `$row["id"]` an array

If you want syntax object :

```
$db    = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$sql   = 'SELECT * FROM events';

$res = $db->query($sql);
$res->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$out = array();
foreach($res as $row) 
{
  $out[] = array(
    'id' => $row->id,
    'title' => $row->name,
    'url' => $row->url,
    'start' => strtotime($row->datetime) . '000',
    'end' => strtotime($row->datetime_end) .'000'
   );
}

echo json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'result' => $out));
exit;
```